# Jackson Custom serializer for custom behaviour of some fields while having default behaviour for rest of the fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

For example I have a POJO defined as below with `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` (version 2.8.3) annotations omitting getters and setters for brevity.

```
class Sample {
     private String foo;
     private String bar;
     private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> data;
}
```

and I would like to write a custom serializer that takes above POJO and generates

```
{
     "foo":"val",
     "bar":"val2",
     "data_1": {
          "someInt":1
     },
     "data_2": {
          "someBoolean":true
     }
}
```

Here `data_1` and `data_2` are keys of main `Map` and their inner attributes are made up of their sub map (nested map). Also, the actual property data shouldn't be present in resulting JSON at all.

Please note that foo and bar are example of fields, actually the pojo has 15+ fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simpler way to do this without using the custom serializer; It was with @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter. Here is a complete example. I am pasting an answer with respect to sample pasted here as it might be useful for others.

```
class Sample {
     private String foo;
     private String bar;

     private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

     @JsonAnyGetter
     public Map<String, Map<String, Object>> getData() {
          return data;
     }

     @JsonAnySetter
     public void set(String key, Map<String, Object>) {
          data.put(key, object);
     }
}
```

[Example](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html)

Answer (score 0):

please correct your class variable **data**,
 it should be like this

```
private Map<String,Map<String, Object>> data;
```

then write a method to serialize like this **:**

```
public static void serializeSample() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Sample sample=new Sample();
    sample.setBar("val2");
    sample.setFoo("val");
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> sampleData=new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> data_3=new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> data_4=new HashMap<>();
    data_3.put("someInt", 1);
    data_4.put("someBoolean", Boolean.TRUE);

    sampleData.put("data_1", data_3);
    sampleData.put("data_2", data_4);
    sample.setData(sampleData);

    try {
        mapper.writeValue(new File("log.txt"), sample);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

this should work fine I think

Comment: Sorry, I can't use a static method for this, the pojo is hooked in with spring and goes to NoSql stores by spring-data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom serializer for that, that iterates over the parent `Map`. For each nested `Map` you can simply use `writeObjectField` with key, value as field name and value.

You also require that all other fields are serialized automatically. You can set a custom serializer on a field only, but you would still get a `data` field in the JSON. You actually want to elevate the contents of data so that they look like fields of `Sample` and that requires a custom serializer for `Sample`. The only way I can think of to automatically serialize everything else except the `data` field is to use reflection

The following serializer will produce JSON as in your question:

```
class SampleSerializer extends StdSerializer<Sample> {
    private static final List<Field> sampleFields;

    public SampleSerializer() { this(null); }
    private SampleSerializer(Class<Sample> t) { super(t); }

    static {
        sampleFields = Arrays.stream(Sample.class.getDeclaredFields())
                .filter(f -> !("data".equals(f.getName())))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Sample sample, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        for (Field field : sampleFields) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                jgen.writeObjectField(field.getName(), field.get(sample));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
            }
        }
        for (Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : sample.getData().entrySet()) {
            jgen.writeObjectField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

You must also specify that `SampleSerializer` will be used for `Sample`, for example by annotating the class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SampleSerializer.class)
class Sample {
```

Comment: This is what I want. However, the two statements
`jgen.writeStringField("foo", sample.getFoo());
jgen.writeStringField("bar", sample.getBar());`

are not desirable because it will be a much complex pojo with many other complex fields. I want some way to say to jackson, serialize foo and bar fields according to annotation and let me specify behaviour for data field

Comment: I have modified to use reflection to *automatically* serialize everything else and *manually* serialize data. It works, but it doesn't look pretty.